# Prevent Read access to Primary replica using Logon triggers

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to implement logon trigger that will deny any connection to primary that is not readonly. However, I have multiple users so I can't add all logins to the the trigger. Also how logon trigger will authenticate if user is part of AD group member?

Comment: Are you trying to guarantee all your read_only traffic goes to a secondary replica?

Comment: You only want read only connections to your primary?

Comment: I am looking only R/W connection to primary replica and read traffic should go to only secondary replicas.  Logon trigger works fine when I include individual login like 'ad\username' or SqlUser but how do I manage if user is part of AD group. I can't include AD group within logon trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with Login triggers. If there is ever a situation where the trigger throws an error, the effects can be cascading, and logins can unexpectedly fail.

An easier way might be to use read only routing to force the connections to a secondary replica when `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`.

Additionally, though not recommended, you could set connections allowed for the primary replica to `ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite`.

That would prevent any connection to a primary replica not explicitly stating application intent as ReadWrite. This is risky though, as all application strings must be updated to explicitly include `ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite`.